# VueJS iterate through the arrays in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, for-loop, object

How can I iterate through the arrays in an object?
What I wish to achieve is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTGo4.png)

This is my code, very simple, it currently outputs the indexes in the proper order, but what I want is the values of the array!

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form class="production">
      <div v-for="(id, index) in ids" :key="index" class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" v-bind:for="ids[index]">{{ labels[index] }}</label>
        <div class="">
          <select v-bind:id="ids[index]" v-bind:name="ids[index]" class="form-control">
            <option v-for="(option, prop, val) in options" :key="val" v-bind:value="option">{{[index]}}{{[val]}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
export default {
  name: "Production",
  data() {
    return {
      labels: ["Menge", "Lieferland", "Verpackung"],
      ids: ["amount", "country", "packing"],
      options: {
        amount: ["100", "300", "500"],
        country: ["Detuschland", "Österreich", "Schweiz"],
        packing: ["Option1", "Option2", "Option3"]
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

I could find nothing about this specific issue anywhere, so I suppose I am doing it wrong and I'm not supposed to make an array inside an object, if that is the case please explain to me how else I should structure my values properly.

I am very new to vueJS and have not very much experience in javascript, though I could get the right output in normal JavaScript with something like this

```
for (var x = 0; x < Object.values(options).length; x++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.values(options)[x].length; i++) {
        console.log(Object.values(options)[x][i])
    }
}
```

VueJS seems a bit more complex than that though

Answer (score 0):

Your second `v-for` loops over the entire `options` object, but most likely you wan to loop over `options[id]`.

Try to update the second `v-for` to this

```
<option v-for="(option, prop, val) in options[id]" :key="val" v-bind:value="option">{{[index]}}{{[val]}}</option>
```